# Magento 2: Retrieve items on Order

Tags: magento2, product, orders, items

I'm trying to retrieve products(which are in order) from order id but it's not working.  Here is the code:

```
namespace My\Trackorder\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $orderRepository;
    private $orderFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, 
         \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
         \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
         \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultFactory
        )
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
         $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()   
    {

        $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'); 

        $order = $this->orderFactory->create();  
        $order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$product = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` class to get order items

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->order = $order;
    ...
}

public function getOrderItems()
{   
    //Get order by order incrementID
    //$order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId('00000005');

    //Get order by orderID
    $order=$this->order->load(1); 

    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        echo $item->getProductId();
        //print_r($item->getData());
    }

    return $orderItems;
}
```